# List or concatenate in SQL window function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, window-functions

A (relatively new to SQL) member of my team was working on writing an SQL query that happened to use a window function.  Upon reviewing I noted that they structured their window function like this:

```
COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Part1+Part2) AS A
```

Which I instantly made a feedback note to say it should be like this:

```
COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Part1, Part2) AS A
```

Both Part1 and Part2 are nvarchars.

Then I paused to reflect and I couldn't actually work out *why* that would be wrong.  As far as I can see that would actually produce identical results (it does).  The actual execution plan is nearly identical aside from an extra Compute Scalar step after the initial table scan on the first query (this is 0% of query cost).  The I/O statistics show that the first version has 5 fewer logical reads (12,665 to 12,670).

So is there any benefit/detriment to using either form, aside from coding conventions?  Is it a case that this works fine in this instance, but in certain circumstances could produce inconsistent results?

Comment: What if the parts are (3,5), (4,4) and (2,6)? Or `('2','12')` and `('21','2')`? Besides, the server will have to calculate all concatenations in advance before partitioning the data, without any benefit from indexing or the outer query's sort order

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both expressions are valid, but they do not do the same thing.

Consider the following data:

```
Part1    Part2
AB       C
A        BC
```

When concatenating strings with `PARTITION BY Part1+Part2` both records fall in the same partition, whereas when using `PARTITION BY Part1, Part2`, they would belong to different partitions.

So the question actually comes down to: what is the correct partitioning criteria for your use case? Usually, unless you are doing something fancy, you want `PARTITION BY Part1, Part2`. But this actually has to be answered from functional perspective, based on your real use case.

Comment: I suspect the first expression also results in bad performance as the server has to calculate all values before partitioning

Comment: Also if either Part1 or Part2 are `NULL` the concatenated result will be `NULL` which may or may not be the intended result

Answer (score 3):

The `PARTITION` expression is exactly that -- an expression.  So you can put almost any form of an expression in there and use that value to partition the rows.

In terms of inconsistent results, you will run into a problem if you have this case:

```
Part1    Part2    Part1 + Part2
'yummy'  'sushi'  'yummysushi'
'yumm'   'ysushi' 'yummysushi'
```

Both rows would be considered to be part of the same partition, even though the columns have different values.

In terms of performance, my only guess is if you have an index or any partitioning scheme set up on those particular columns, you *might* get an improvement there.

Best bet is to use the second case you specified `(Part1, Part2)`.